# Javascript Search a substring in a string, and get output

Tags: javascript

I need to create a automatic tools to help our regularly job.
Some output string that can be generated, so I can create report automatically (since a lot of parameter have to be done)

**What I have create**

```
Output Device : <input type="text" id="myText" value="">

<p>Click the button to display the value of the value attribute of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var y= document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y
}
</script>
```

**Goal :**
Input data all data (on example below) and get output (on result example below)

**Source Data Input:**

**Example 1 :**

*Cisco IOS Software, C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASEK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)*
*IDSWR010 uptime is 4 weeks, 5 days, 6 hours, 52 minutes*
*System returned to ROM by power-on*

**Example 2 :**

*Cisco IOS Software, C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASEK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)*
*IDSWR012 uptime is 4 weeks, 5 days, 6 hours, 17 minutes*
*System returned to ROM by power-on*

**Requirement Output**
**Example 1 :**

*C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASEK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE5*

*4 weeks, 5 days, 6 hours, 52 minutes*
*power-on*

**Example 2 :**

*C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASEK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE5*
*4 weeks, 5 days, 6 hours, 17 minutes*
*power-on*

Since I'm a network engineer and have almost nothing knowledge for programming.
Need you help to provide me the example code, so I can continue it :)

Thank you so much for all your help

Comment: This is not a place to get your home work done by someone. Do research work and ask for some help only if you're blocked.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a lot of string/array manipulation.

First, take your input and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it into an array on each new line.

```
let lines = str.split(/\n/g);
```

For your first line split it on the comma, take a [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) of the array you need and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it back together with a comma.

```
let first = lines[0].split(', ').slice(1,3).join(', ');
```

e.g C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASEK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE5

Next line: use a [`regex` to match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) a series of numbers followed by a space followed by some lowercase letters and an optional comma. Take a slice of that returned array, and join with spaces.

```
let second = lines[1].match(/\d+ [a-z]+,?/g).slice(1, 5).join(' ');
```

e.g 4 weeks, 5 days, 6 hours, 52 minutes

Next! Simply [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the part of the string you don't want with an empty string (I've made the assumption that the string will always be "System returned to ROM by [something]".

```
let third = lines[2].replace('System returned to ROM by ', '');
```

e.g. power-on

Finally, stick all the rendered strings in an array and join them together with new lines again.

```
let out = [first, second, third].join('\n');
```

Final output:

```
C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASEK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE5
4 weeks, 5 days, 6 hours, 52 minutes
power-on
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/28qkfgfn/)**

Comment: Hi Andy, 

Really appreaciate for your help
But I still don't know where I should put your command, I have try multiple ways but the javascript not working

Could you help to show me? I'm not programmer so I'm not familiar with coding..

Comment: Is `myText` the input that contains the input string you want to convert?

Comment: [I updated the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28qkfgfn/16/). If you add your input string to the textarea and click the button the output will appear in the demo paragraph. Not sure that's precisely what you want, but it's probably close enough...